Defined Rules get not called in Scrapy
I am currently working with the Python library Scrapy and I am inheriting from the CrawlSpider so that I can override/define custom Rules. I have defined rules that should block all URLs with auth/ and allow only URLs with /tags.
My solution:
class DockerhubDockerRegistrySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dockerhubDockerQueriedRegistrySpider"
    allowed_domains = ["hub.docker.com"]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow='/tags'),
            callback='parse_additional_page',
            follow=False
        ),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(deny='auth/'),
            follow=False
        ),

    )

The Problem is that when the follow methode is called, it automatically calls always https://hub.docker.com/auth/profile and this page cannot be accessed, so I want to block it but somehow my rules do not fire.
Follow URL call:
yield response.follow(
                additional_data_url_absolute,
                self.parse_additional_page,
                cb_kwargs=dict(item=item),
                meta=dict(
                    playwright=True,
                    playwright_include_page=True,
                    playwright_page_methods={
                        "wait_for_page_load": PageMethod("wait_for_selector", 'body[aria-describedby="global-progress"]')
                    },

                )
            )

Follow Callback:
def parse_additional_page(self, response, item):
    self.logger.info("Additional page meta: %s", response.meta)
    self.logger.info("Additional page HTML: %s", response.css('title::text').get())
    self.logger.info("Additional page HTML Repo-Name: %s", response.css('h2[data-testid="repoName"]::text').get())
    item['additional_data'] = response.css('h2[data-testid="repoName"]::text').get()
    yield item

Debug log:
2024-07-16 20:28:17 [scrapy-playwright] DEBUG: [Context=default] Response: <401 https://hub.docker.com/auth/profile>
2024-07-16 20:28:18 [scrapy-playwright] DEBUG: [Context=default] Response: <401 https://hub.docker.com/auth/profile>
2024-07-16 20:28:19 [scrapy-playwright] DEBUG: [Context=default] Request: <POST 2024-07-16 20:28:19 [scrapy-playwright] DEBUG: [Context=default] Request: <GET https://hub.docker.com/auth/profile> (resource type: fetch, referrer: https://hub.docker.com/search?q=python&page=1)

2024-07-16 20:44:23 [scrapy-playwright] DEBUG: [Context=default] Request: <GET https://hub.docker.com/auth/profile> (resource type: fetch, referrer: https://hub.docker.com/r/google/guestbook-python-redis/tags)

How to block requests for  https://hub.docker.com/auth/profile?
My whole solution:
class DockerhubDockerRegistrySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "dockerhubDockerQueriedRegistrySearchSpiderTemp"
allowed_domains = ["hub.docker.com"]

rules = (
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(allow=r'/tags$'),  # Only allow URLs that end with '/tags'
        callback='parse_additional_page',
        follow=False
    ),

    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(allow='search'),
        callback='parse_registry',
        follow=True
    ),

)

def __init__(self, query=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DockerhubDockerRegistrySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.query = query
    self.start_urls = [f'https://hub.docker.com/search?q={query}&page={i}' for i in range(1, 12)]

def start_requests(self):
    for index, url in enumerate(self.start_urls, start=1):
        self.logger.info(f"Starting request: {url}")
        yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                meta=dict(
                    page_number=index,
                    playwright=True,
                    playwright_include_page=True,
                    playwright_page_methods={
                        "wait_for_search_results": PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "div#searchResults"),
                    }
                ),
                callback=self.parse_registry
            )

async def parse_registry(self, response):
    page = response.meta["playwright_page"]

    if await page.title() == "hub.docker.com":
        await page.close()
        await page.context.close()

    page_number = response.meta.get("page_number")
    if page_number is None:
        self.logger.warning("Page number not found in meta: %s", response.url)
        return

    search_results = response.xpath('//a[@data-testid="imageSearchResult"]')

    for result in search_results:
        item = DockerImageItem()
        item['page_number'] = page_number
        item['name'] = result.css('[data-testid="product-title"]::text').get()

        uploader_elem = result.css("span::text").re(r"^By (.+)")

        if uploader_elem:
            item["uploader"] = uploader_elem[0].strip()
        else:
            official_icon = result.css('[data-testid="official-icon"]')
            verified_publisher_icon = result.css(
                '[data-testid="verified_publisher-icon"]'
            )

            item["is_official_image"] = bool(official_icon)
            item["is_verified_publisher"] = bool(verified_publisher_icon)

        item['is_official_image'] = bool(result.css('[data-testid="official-icon"]'))
        item['is_verified_publisher'] = bool(result.css('[data-testid="verified_publisher-icon"]'))
        item['last_update'] = self.parse_update_string(result.css('span:contains("Updated")::text').get())

        item['description'] = result.xpath(
            './/span[contains(text(), "Updated")]/ancestor::div[1]/following-sibling::p[1]/text()').get()

        item['chips'] = result.css('[data-testid="productChip"] span::text').getall()

        # Extract pulls last week
        pulls_elem = (
            result.css('p:contains("Pulls:")')
            .xpath("following-sibling::p/text()")
            .get()
        )
        item["pulls_last_week"] = (
            pulls_elem.replace(",", "") if pulls_elem else None
        )

        item['downloads'] = result.css('[data-testid="DownloadIcon"] + p::text').get()
        item['stars'] = result.css('svg[data-testid="StarOutlineIcon"] + span > strong::text').get()

        # Clean up text fields
        item['name'] = item['name'].strip() if item['name'] else None
        item['description'] = item['description'].strip() if item['description'] else None
        item['downloads'] = item['downloads'].strip() if item['downloads'] else None
        item['pulls_last_week'] = item['pulls_last_week'].replace(",", "") if item['pulls_last_week'] else None
        item['stars'] = item['stars'].strip() if item['stars'] else None

        additional_data_url = result.attrib.get('href')
        if additional_data_url and '/r/' or '/_/' in additional_data_url and '/tags' in additional_data_url:
            additional_data_url_absolute = f"https://hub.docker.com{additional_data_url}/tags"
            self.logger.info("Entered Additional Page: %s", additional_data_url_absolute)

            yield response.follow(
                additional_data_url_absolute,
                callback=self.parse_additional_page,
                cb_kwargs=dict(item=item),
                meta=dict(
                    playwright=True,
                    playwright_include_page=True,
                    errback=self.close_context_on_error,
                    playwright_page_methods={
                        "wait_for_page_load": PageMethod("wait_for_selector", 'div[data-testid="repotagsTagListItem"]'),
                    },
                    playwright_context_kwargs={
                        "ignore_https_errors": True,
                    }
                )
            )
        else:
            self.logger.error("No additional page available for: %s", item['name'])
            yield item

async def close_context_on_error(self, failure):
    page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
    await page.close()
    await page.context.close()

def parse_additional_page(self, response, item):

    self.logger.info("Additional page meta: %s", response.meta)
    self.logger.info("Additional page HTML: %s", response.css('title::text').get())
    self.logger.info("Additional page HTML Repo-Name: %s", response.css('h2[data-testid="repoName"]::text').get())
    item['additional_data'] = response.css('h2[data-testid="repoName"]::text').get()
    return item


@staticmethod
def parse_update_string(update_string):
    return update_string.strip() if update_string else None


I think LinkExtractor does only filter out links in the HTML, not requests, that are fired by the js.

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but I assume that you are searching for Python images and then trying to extract tag information for each of them.
I don't actually think that the https://hub.docker.com/auth/profile requests should be an issue.
The crawler below grabs the links from the first page of results and then visits the page for each image.
import logging

from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

logging.getLogger('scrapy-playwright').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger('playwright').setLevel(logging.WARNING)

class DockerhubDockerRegistrySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dockerhub"
    allowed_domains = ["hub.docker.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://hub.docker.com/search?q=python"
        yield Request(
            url,
            callback=self.parse,
            meta=dict(
                playwright=True,
                playwright_include_page=True,
                playwright_page_methods=[
                    PageMethod('wait_for_selector', '#searchResults .MuiStack-root > a.MuiLink-root', state='visible'),
                ]
            ),
        )

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]

        links = response.css("#searchResults .MuiStack-root > a.MuiLink-root::attr(href)").getall()

        for link in links:
            link = response.urljoin(link)

            yield Request(
                link,
                callback=self.parse_image,
                meta=dict(
                    playwright=True,
                    playwright_include_page=True,
                    playwright_page_methods=[
                        PageMethod('wait_for_selector', '.MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-h2', state='visible'),
                    ]
                ),
            )

        await page.close()

    async def parse_image(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]

        title = response.css(".MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-h2::text").get()

        await page.close()

        yield {"title": title}

The most important thing that I found when putting this together is that you reduce the rate at which you send requests, otherwise you start getting 429 responses. So I have the following in settings.py:
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 0.5
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = True

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 1


I need to call the search function scrape the result list and follow every item of the result via a link, to get to the https://hub.docker.com/r/rancher/library-busybox/tags page in order to get a combined result of the tags and the general docker-image data. But this leads to unholy long response times and too much requets.

do you have any solutions for that or approach-suggestions?

To help me avoid guessing what you are doing, please include the whole of your current spider in the question.

First of all thanks you for trying and beeing polite hahah. pretty rare here.
i've updated the post with my whole solution.
thanks in advance!

Of course! Everybody should be polite. :) Let me take a quick look.

Okay, I have looked at your code. There's a lot going on there. Your problem is with the URL navigation. There's a lot of code that doesn't relate to that. For clarity can you please strip your code down to a minimal example that illustrates the problem? Thank you!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78764659/scraping-all-pages-using-scrapy-crawler-linkextractor-rules
here is a link. i have broke down the problem into a smaller code chunk.(the problem changed a bit :))

No problem. I have provided an answer to that question too.
