Scraping all pages using Scrapy-Crawler & LinkExtractor-Rules
I am trying to scrape dockerhub.com with the scrapy-vertical approach using the Crawler and i need to define a rule which gathers all pages with the following pattern:

https://hub.docker.com/search?q=python&page=1
https://hub.docker.com/search?q=python&page=2
https://hub.docker.com/search?q=python&page=3
https://hub.docker.com/search?q=python&page=4
https://hub.docker.com/search?q=python&page=....

I have tried using:
 rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'\?q=.*&page=\d+'),
         follow=True,
         process_request=set_playwright_true,
         callback=parse_page
         ),
)

 def parse_page(self, response):
    self.logger.info("Parsing page: %s", response.url)

    for result in response.css('div#searchResults div.some-class'):
        yield {
            'title': result.css('h2 a::text').get(),
            'link': result.css('h2 a::attr(href)').get(),
        }

but this approach gathers just one page.
Has anyone an idea how to get every page based on my pattern?

I don't see any links in the page that match your rule.
Why not just iterate over the page indices?
import re
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.spiders.crawl import CrawlSpider
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod
from twisted.internet.error import TimeoutError

import time

CSS_IMG_LIST = ".MuiStack-root > a > .MuiPaper-root"

class DockerHubSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dockerhub"
    allowed_domains = ["hub.docker.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            "https://hub.docker.com/search?q=python&page=1",
            callback=self.parse,
            meta={
                "playwright": True,
                "playwright_include_page": True,
                "playwright_page_methods": [
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", CSS_IMG_LIST),
                ],
            },
        )

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        time.sleep(5)

        await page.close()

        # Get index for current page.
        index = int(re.search("([0-9]+)$", response.url).groups()[0])

        yield Request(
            f"https://hub.docker.com/search?q=python&page={index+1}",
            callback=self.parse,
            errback=self.handle_error,
            meta={
                "playwright": True,
                "playwright_include_page": True,
                "playwright_page_methods": [
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", CSS_IMG_LIST),
                ],
            },
        )

    def handle_error(self, failure):
        if failure.check(TimeoutError):
            raise CloseSpider("TimeoutError encountered")

There are certainly more elegant ways to do this, but the code above will start on the first page of Python images and keep progressing until the last (which is currently page 100) before stopping.
This is what I have in settings.py:
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}
PLAYWRIGHT_DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000
PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSER_TYPE = "chromium"
PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS = {"headless": False}

I suggest not using headless while developing so that you can see what's happening in the browser window.
